# How to set the flag in header table on the basis of lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have got sales header and sales line table. e.g. SalesID = 1 have got 2 sales lines in sales line table.

**SalesHeader:**
Sales ID = 1, Active = 1

I would like to set Active flag to 0 if all line's sales status is invoiced

**SalesLines**
SalesID = 1 , lineNum = 1, SalesStatus = Invoiced
SalesID = 1 , lineNum = 2, SalesStatus = Open Order

In this case I do not want to change the Active flag to 0 in header table as 1 line in same sales order is Open order.

If all lines invoiced than i would like to change the active flag = 0.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: This sounds like a value that should be displayed in a `VIEW`.

Comment: Create table dbo.salesheader (
 SalesID  INT,
 Active   BIT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.salesheader 
values (1,1)

Create table dbo.salesline (
 SalesID  INT,
 lineNum  int,
 salesStatus varchar(20)
)

insert into dbo.salesline
values (1,1,'Invoiced'),
    (1,2,'Open Order')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Find the IDs you need to update. You can do it checking the number of all available salesLines of an ID and comparing it the total of "Invoiced" count, which should be matching to its flag get updated. You can save those ids to a separate temp table as you may also use table type of variable or "with cte" structure.

```
SELECT SalesId
into #SalesHavingAllInvoicedLines
from 
   (
      SELECT SalesId,
             COUNT(*) totCount,
             SUM(CASE WHEN SalesStatus ='invoiced' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) InCount 
      FROM SalesLines 
      GROUP BY SalesId
   ) x 
WHERE x.totCount=x.InCount
```

2- Do the update using "inner join" to the temp table you've created on Step 1.

```
update s
set Active=0
from SalesHeader s
inner join #SalesHavingAllInvoicedLines s2 on s.SalesId=s2.SalesId
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, `exists` performs better than `count` or `sum` when a precise value isn't needed. A fairly clear expression of what you described is:

```
update SalesHeader
  set Active = 0
  where not exists ( -- Note: NOT exists.
    -- Find all of the corresponding sales lines with a sales status other than "Invoiced" .
    select 42
      from SalesLines as SL
        where SL.SalesId = SalesHeader.SalesId and SL.SalesStatus <> 'Invoiced' );
```

An index on the `SalesLines` table on `SalesId` and including `SalesStatus` would be useful.

Note that if there are *no* rows in `SalesLines` that have a matching `SalesId` then `Active` will be set to `0`.